# error deploying to aws container from visual studio

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, visual-studio-2017

I installed the **visual studio aws tookit for vs**, created a dotnet core app, deployed, and after a few tries deployed it and reached from browser.
Now I'm trying to deploy an updated version of the app and I have problems: after a few test I see that now the problem is the creation of the task that gives me the error (in the aws console)

```
CannotPullContainerError: failed to register layer: expected integer
```

What does it means? how can I fix it? After I saw the app running seems to me I didn't change anything in the configuration files.